# Is there a way to set up Babel to continuously transpile and/or minify a src folder to a compiled folder?

Tags: babeljs, minify

Starting with an empty directory, is it possible to do that?  Should I use `stage-0` like it is on the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl)?

I hope to transpile it just like how ReactJS does it.  For some reason, I always got an error for just a file containing:

```
let obj = { a: 1 };

let newObj = {
    ...obj,
    ha: 3
};
```

Other times, I can transpile a file, but if I transpile a folder, it'd say:

```
foo.js: Cannot read property 'contexts' of null
```

The commands I tried included:

```
npx babel src --out-dir compiled --presets=es2015,react,minify --watch
```

but the errors I mentioned above appeared. Also, when I do

```
npm install babel-minify
```

it reported

```
found 2489 vulnerabilities (849 low, 306 moderate, 1329 high, 5 critical)
```

There is also a notice

> As of v7.0.0-beta.55, we've removed Babel's Stage presets.
>   Please consider reading our blog post on this decision at
>   https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets
>   for more details. TL;DR is that it's more beneficial in the
>     long run to explicitly add which proposals to use.

and I wonder what should be done.

Is it possible to

1. just continuously minify a folder
2. transpile some ES6 or ES7, 8 syntax that are not yet commonly supported
3. transpile JSX as well

?

Answer (score 1):

I have found some reliable ways to make it work, although I am not sure when I should use `babel.config.json` and when to use `.babelrc.json` or `.babelrc`.  It seems I have to run babel as `./node_modules/.bin/babel` and is it true if I don't `npm install babel` using the `-g` option.

Here is what works:

1. create a folder, such as `TryBabel`
2. `cd TryBabel`
3. Go to https://babeljs.io/setup.html and click "CLI"
4. You need a `package.json`, so use `npm init` and just press Enter a few times
5. It should lead you to install
   a. `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli`
   b. now look at your `package.json`. Remove the `script` about `test` but use this: `"build": "babel src -d lib"`
6. Now `npm run build` or `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib` should work, but make sure you have some `.js` files in the `src` folder. The transpiled result will be in the `lib` folder.
7. Now to transpile things into "pre ES6", just follow the `@babel/preset-env` instructions:
   a. `npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev`
   b. make your `babel.config.json` to contain `{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }`

Now you can use `npm run build` to transpile once, or use `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib --watch` to keep on running it and "watch" the `src` folder and transpile files in it when the files change.

To do minification or make it work with JSX/React, see

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-minify
and
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

and make sure your `babel.config.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [

    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-react"],
    ["minify"]
  ]
}
```

and remove `minify` if you don't want the code to be minified.